Congruence relation in monoids
Suppose $(M, \ast)$ is a monoid and $\sim$ is a congruence relation on $M$, i.e. $\sim$ is an equivalence relation such that: $x_1 \sim y_1$ and $x_2 \sim y_2$ imply that $x_1 \ast x_2 \sim y_1 \ast y_2$.
Is it true that $x \sim y$ implies the existence of two elements $a, b \in M$ with $a \sim0 \sim b$ such that $x \ast a = y \ast b$?
The converse of this implication can be shown through straightforward calculation. I know this result holds for groups, but I am having difficulty determining if it applies to general monoids.

No, just thought of $(\mathbb{N} \cup{0}, +)$ with the relation $x \sim y$ if $x, y$ are both positive or equal. In this case, $2 \sim 3$ and $x \sim 0$ implies $x = 0$. Besides that, $2 +0 \neq 3 + 0$.

See my answer below.

Minimal counterexample. Let $M = \{1, c, c^2\}$ with $c^3 = c$ and let $\sim$ be the congruence defined by $c \sim c^2$. The identity $1$ is the unique element in its congruence class, but $1 \cdot c \not= c^2$. Also observe that $c^2 \not= 1$.

This is false for congruences on monoids that are not groups.
In fact, it is possible to have a congruence relation $\sim$ other than equality for which $a=e$ is the only element of $M$ with $a \sim e$ (where $e$ is the identity of $M$). Note that $0$ as the identity is reserved for additive monoids and has a different meaning for multiplicative monoids ($a+0=0+a=a$ vs. $a*0=0*a=0$).
For example, there is a congruence $\sim$ on the additive monoid of nonnegative integers for which $x \sim y$ but $x \not\sim 0$ for all positive integers $x$ and $y$. For this congruence, $1 \sim 2$, but there are no two nonnegative integers $a$ and $b$ for which $a \sim 0 \sim b$ and $1+a=2+b$.
